# Personalize storyboard segues

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard

I wanted to ask: but in storyboard Xcode 4.3 are you able to personalize the segues, or create your own segues, or are you forced to use custom, modal, popover? even because only modal works for me, the others (push, replace...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom segue by subclassing [`UIStoryboardSegue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010911-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2).

Comment: but how can you create one yourself?

Comment: as I said, subclass `UISToryboardSegue` and put your animation code into `- (void)perform`. An example I found with some google: http://www.cmumobileapps.com/2011/11/04/a-short-tutorial-on-custom-segues/